# Show final score in android quiz android studio

Tags: android

```
        I am working on a quiz app that requires four questions,
```

one check box for multiple answers, a radio button for questions with only one answer and a free text box. The sum total is supposed to be added at the end with the calculation being done via if/else statments.
I have created a button that is supposed to submit the test however instead of adding all the answers to present a score it only increased the value by one.

Are there any resources that I can be pointed to in order to learn why this is happening?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/loud"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Question1"
                android:text=" Question 1. Name  the main characters in a story about witches and wizards"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Hermione"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Hermione"


                android:textSize="20sp"></CheckBox>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Harry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Harry"
                android:textSize="20sp"></CheckBox>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Ron"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Ron"
                android:textSize="20sp"></CheckBox>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                android:text=" Question 2. Who dropped harry off with the dursleys?"
                android:textSize="20sp">


            </TextView>

            <RadioGroup

                android:id="@+id/team"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/hagrid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="hagrid"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text=" Question 3. Who was famous for saying the fan favorite line: Turn to page 394?"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Hagrid"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"

                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/old"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:text="Dumbledore"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/hero"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Snape"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RadioGroup>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/book"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:text=" Question 4. the answer is rowling"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/answer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="Enter Answer"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Click me to submit the answer"
                android:layout_marginTop="960dp"

                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:onClick="finalscore"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rowling"
                android:layout_marginTop="1100dp"

                android:text=" the answer to question four will show here"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/finalscore"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="score"
                android:text="Click me to submit your answers"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/score"
                android:layout_marginTop="1100dp"

                android:text="will show here"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

    enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/loud"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Question1"
                android:text=" Question 1. Name  the main characters in a story about witches and wizards"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Hermione"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Hermione"


                android:textSize="20sp"></CheckBox>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Harry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Harry"
                android:textSize="20sp"></CheckBox>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Ron"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Ron"
                android:textSize="20sp"></CheckBox>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                android:text=" Question 2. Who dropped harry off with the dursleys?"
                android:textSize="20sp">


            </TextView>

            <RadioGroup

                android:id="@+id/team"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/hagrid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="hagrid"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text=" Question 3. Who was famous for saying the fan favorite line: Turn to page 394?"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Hagrid"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"

                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/old"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:text="Dumbledore"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/hero"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Snape"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RadioGroup>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/book"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:text=" Question 4. the answer is rowling"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/answer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="Enter Answer"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Click me to submit the answer"
                android:layout_marginTop="960dp"

                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:onClick="finalscore"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rowling"
                android:layout_marginTop="1100dp"

                android:text=" the answer to question four will show here"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/finalscore"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="score"
                android:text="Click me to submit your answers"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/score"
                android:layout_marginTop="1100dp"

                android:text="will show here"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unrelated but important. You don't need RelativeLayout for this and you don't need those huge margins and remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from all child views (you only need to have it in the root view which is ScrollView in this example). Also change that RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and remove all the margins from views. and because you have an EditText in the activity if you don't want it to get the focus by default (which opens the keyboard), you need to set focusable and focusableInTouchMode to true for the root view (doesn't work on ScrollView though so I put it in the LinearLayout).:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
   ```
2. Put the RadioButtons that belong to the same question inside a RadioGroup, this way only one of the buttons could be selected at the same time for example:

   ```
   <RadioGroup
       android:id="@+id/q1_radio_group"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/hagrid"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="hagrid"
           android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
           android:textSize="20sp" />

       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/snape"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="snape"
           android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
           android:textSize="20sp" />

   </RadioGroup>
   ```
3. Do not use onClick inside the xml (it is not recommended), instead use `setOnClickListner()` on your Button inside your activity.
4. Instead of those CheckBoxes for the 1st question just use another RadioGroup.
5. now inside the onClick method of your submit button check for each RadioGroup's selected item id and check if it is correct. if it was add 1 to score. And use getText from the EditText and check if that is correct as well and then show the score inside a text view.

   ```
   RadioGroup rg = findViewById(R.id.q1_radio_group);
   if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.hagrid){
       // add to score
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code, you hard coded the quiz questions. Which is not recommended.
Anyway to address your questions, there are two ways you can get the total score.
1. Take a field variable and update it for every answer chosen and display it on button click.
2. Store in shared preferences and display the total value.